# NPM run build change name file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How to rename a file when I use the npm run build command. I want to generate a file with `bundle.js` name instead of `2.31b4fde6.chunk.js`

Answer (score 4):

Use following syntax in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
}
```

It will create main.js under dist folder.

Comment: I use react-create-app so where I can use this code? Wher is webpack.config.js

Comment: i would prefer to use webpack its quite simple but quite useful.

Comment: you have to eject

Comment: @PawełBaca you cant use config your webpack in create-react-app but you could either eject or use sth like craco or react-app-rewired instead.